# Facebook Graph API /search?q=keyword does not give all results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This isn't only limited to programming, but also when I interact with Facebook's search bar as a user.

When I interact with their `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/search` endpoint. I use the following query to get all hackathons events `?q=hackathon&type=event`. I get to see 20 hackathons or so from all over the world.

That's it.

When I change the query from `hackathon` to `hackathon%20dutch` or `dutch%20hackathon` (or normal spaces, depending on how I do it), then I get to see a hackathon that is not in the original results list. At the moment of writing it's the Dutch Open Hackathon. Furthermore, it's the only result in the whole list!

I'm surprised by this.

I've got two questions:

1. Why do I see so few results?
2. How do I get more complete
   results?

Note: I see the exact same results as a normal Facebook user, since I supply my access token that is generated for me via the graph API explorer.

Comment: You get what you get, and that's it. The search results are tailored to the specific user. The endpoint is not meant to allow you a complete search of "everything there is on Facebook" in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the info :) Is there a way to do this?